# IntelliJ Linux javafx errors with valid JDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

Currently trying to build my project on a new install of kubuntu 17.10.

I have openjdk currently installed and intellij(IDE) but when i try to build my project i get these errors.

```
Error:(20, 1) java: package javafx.scene.input does not exist
Error:(28, 26) java: package javafx.application does not exist
Error:(29, 26) java: package javafx.application does not exist
Error:(30, 19) java: package javafx.fxml does not exist
Error:(31, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(32, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(33, 27) java: package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
Error:(34, 27) java: package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
Error:(35, 20) java: package javafx.stage does not exist
```

Am i missing something?? I added the class path to it but still not registering....

i already ran sudo apt-get install openjfx and the classpath appears to have been added.

Comment: OpenJDK doesn't include JavaFX: you need to install it separately.

Comment: i did by "sudo apt-get install openjfx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue.

What i had to do is remove the JDK in my IDE, then add it again. It was then able to pull all the requires jars.

Issue resolved.